# Get bytes of encoded non-printable string

Tags: powershell, escaping, sqlmap, non-printing-characters

When I dump a table entries with [sqlmap](https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap) with `--hex` key, I get bytes of password hash correctly, but powershell represents these bytes as string. All non-printable characters are escaped and I get these bytes as `\\?e1\n\\?dc9I\\?baY\\?ab\\?beV\\?e0W\\?f2\x0f\\?88>`. How can I unescape this string to get then original bytes from it?

Answer (score 0):

Going from string to bytes is going to depend on whether it is a string per byte, if so try this:

```
# simulated output as a byte per string
$str = [string[]][char[]][byte[]](0xE1,0x0A,0xDC,0x39,0x49,0xBA,0x59,0xAB,0xBE,0x56,0xE0,0x57,0xF2,0x0F,0x88,0x3E)

# convert to bytes
$str | Foreach {[byte][char]$_}
```

If it is a single string, try this:

```
# simulated output as a single string containing all the bytes
$ofs=''
$str = [string][char[]][byte[]](0xE1,0x0A,0xDC,0x39,0x49,0xBA,0x59,0xAB,0xBE,0x56,0xE0,0x57,0xF2,0x0F,0x88,0x3E)

# convert to bytes
$str.ToCharArray() | % {[byte]$_}
```

Comment: Sorry, if I'm not mistaken you convert bytes to string but in my case I need the opposite. I know that the value in database is `E10ADC3949BA59ABBE56E057F20F883E` and it is successfully dumped by sqlmap as hex. But powershell represents it in command line like `\\?e1\n\\?dc9I\\?baY\\?ab\\?beV\\?e0W\\?f2\x0f\\?88>`. I need to get first value from the second value.

Comment: In my oppinion the first value is represented in shell as ASCII characters. There are non-printable characters in this string, so they are encoded somehow and the second value appears. The question is - what is this encoding?

Comment: What output do you get from this: `sqlmap --hex <rest of your params>  | Foreach {$_.GetType().FullName}`

Comment: As output I have a lot of `System.String` lines

Comment: If the output is System.String, try this.  `$str = sqlmap --hex <rest of your params> ; $str.ToCharArray() | Foreach { [byte]$_ }`

Comment: A lot of strings eh?  Is there one per byte?  If so, drop the `.ToCharArray()` call.

Comment: A bit more experimenting (guessing on what your output actually looks like) and you may need to cast to char first e.g. `$str | Foreach {[byte][char]$_}`

Comment: I get nothing, I guess because sqlmap tool requires user interaction. If I take only the second value showed earlier as the value of $str (in double quotes), I have `92
63
56
50
124
92
63
99
98
14
92
63
101
97
92
63
56
97
112
108
76
52
92
63
97
49
104
92
63
57
49
92
63
102
56
78
123`.

Comment: But is that really what the utility outputs?  This is the crux of the issue.  If you assign the output of the utility to $str, what is in $str[0], $str[1], etc.

Comment: The thing is that the tool outputs a lot of text plus it prompts user what sql-injection texhniques to use, what parameters test, etc.

Comment: What you do in `$str | Foreach {[byte][char]$_}` is taking every symbol of second string presented earlier and printing it's char code. As I wrote earlier ago `In my oppinion the first value is represented in shell as ASCII characters. There are non-printable characters in this string, so they are encoded somehow and the second value appears. The question is - what is this encoding? `

Comment: What code page is your shell using? Run `chcp` or `[console]::inputencoding`.  BTW you might try asking about this issue on the project's GitHub repo https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/issues

Comment: chcp output says that code page is 866. Yeah, I think about this now too